# What does * in the controller means?

Tags: magento-2.1, controllers

There is this code in Magento 2 in

> Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save.php

```
if ($redirectBack === 'new') 
{            
   $resultRedirect->setPath('catalog/*/new'
                           ,['set' => $productAttributeSetId
                                ,'type' => $productTypeId]);
```

Can anyone tell me what does **'catalog/*/new'** refers to? I have checked the controller folder and haven't found new.php file anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the current part of the route will be used in that position. So if the current route is `catalog/product/index` then `catalog/*/new` will be `catalog/product/new`.